# Where in clause using order by to get the result

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `fz_users` WHERE `id` in ('6', '1', '30', '34', '11', '3', '2', '7', '4', '24', '221')
```

I am using this query to show the user data and 6,1,30.... are the ids of the user but my problem is that i need in the same order like I am giving in it ie 6,1,30,34,11,3,2

Comment: and in you case it ignores order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE id IN ('6', '1', '30', '34', '11', '3', '2', '7', '4', '24', '221')
ORDER BY FIELD(id,'6', '1', '30', '34', '11', '3', '2', '7', '4', '24', '221');
```